# How would I make my .env file work in my .py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, discord.py

Making a discord bot and I want to store variables in a `.env` file.

It throws this exception:

```
  File "c:\Users\Adam\Documents\DiscordBot\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Before I moved the variables to the `.env` file it worked fine.

```
#.py
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import discord

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
GUILD = os.getenv("GUILD_NAME")

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f"{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n"
        f"{guild.name}(id: {guild.id}"
    )

client.run(TOKEN)

#.env
DISCORD_TOKEN=my_discord_token
GUILD_NAME=Testing
```

My `.env` and `.py` are in the same folder.

Comment: What happens if you print the value of TOKEN and GUILD after they are loaded? Because it sounds like they are NoneType

Comment: You should renew your discord token immediately. Someone else can take your token and use your bot freely.

Comment: The TOKEN was regenerated.

Comment: It prints None None

Comment: The same error occurs if I run it in command prompt if that means anything.

Comment: @adamm try passing the full path of the .env file, like `load_dotenv("/foo/bar/.env")`. also try `load_dotenv(find_dotenv())` after importing `find_dotenv` as well. python-dotenv can be finnicky somtimes

Comment: Alright, give me a sec.

Comment: Like this? ``load_dotenv("DiscordBot/vars.env")``

Comment: @adamm ah. so `load_dotenv()` actually looks for `.env` file. because your .env file is `vars.env`, you should try `load_dotenv("vars.env")` first.

Comment: oh alright, sorry

Comment: wait what the, it works now.
thank you so much, I have been working on this problem for hours

Comment: @adamm glad it worked. I posted it as an answer as well, feel free to accept if it helped.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: nevermind I found out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python-dotenv`'s `load_env()` searches for a `.env` file in the same directory as where it's being executed.
If you change your `.env` filename to a custom one, like `var.env`, you must specify the filename: `load_env("var.env")`